# Do smartphones require additional hardware to communicate using DSRC?

Tags: mobile

[Dedicated short-range communications](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedicated_short-range_communications) are one-way or two-way short-range to medium-range wireless communication channels specifically designed for automotive use.  DSRC uses the 5.9 GHz band allocated by the US govt.

Does a smart phone need any additional hardware to send/receive data using this wireless communication protocol?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very likely, yes, as it's not the same protocol as 802.11a (even if you could get the 5ghz radio onto the right band)